# ajax call in a controller : $http is not defined

Tags: angularjs

I need a ajax call inside the function but if i use $http i am getting $http is not defined pls suggest me my code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ContactController($scope) {
        $scope.contacts = ["hi@email.com", "hello@email.com"];

        $scope.add = function() {
            alert("panduuuu")
       $scope.contacts.push($scope.newcontact);
       $scope.newcontact = "";

       $http.get('http://localhost:8080/ProjectManagement/REST/Login/Check?usename='+usename+'&password='+password+'')
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config,response){
               alert("insideee")
               var json = JSON.stringify(data);
               var getresponseText = JSON.parse(json);
               var value=getresponseText.responseText;                   
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config,response) {



        });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: try to inject $http service here
function ContactController($scope, $http) {

Answer (score 1):

**Correctly Passing Params**

You should pass parameters to a http request like this

```
$http.get('http://MyServerIP:ServerPort/APICall', { params: { user_id: $scope._id } })
```

Also you should make calles like this in a service or a factory to be reused if needed

**Add Your Correct Services**

you also forgot to add `$http` in your function, next to `$scope`

```
ContactController($scope, $http)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject the `$http` service to your controller like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ContactController($scope, $http) {
       ...
```

Answer (score -1):

You haven't injected the $http service into your controller.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('ContactController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http){
   //awesome stuff
});

<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="ContactController">
    </div>
</div>
```

On a side note you should avoid registering controllers like you are and use `.controller` or `.service` etc. Also the array notation allows Angulars dependency system to work if you intend on minifying your JS.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

Comment: Why the down-vote? Can't improve my answers if i don't know what the issues are.